# Disabled SELinux then rebooted, but reboot seems to have hanged?

Tags: linux, selinux

I disabled SELinux by editing /etc/selinux/config to include the line

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

This change requires rebooting to activate, so I did that. I'm now sitting in front of a black screen with 'Attempting Boot From Hard Drive' along the top that has been like that for more than 30 minutes or so.

Is there some processes going on that could be related to changing the SELinux settings? I've read that rebooting when you've activated SELinux can take a while due to re-labelling, but not the other way around. I'd expect it to get a little further into the boot process as well.

Obviously many other things could be happening, but this seems the prime culprit. Any ideas how to recover?

This is a RHEL6 machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a grub> prompt after that (press enter), execute the following commands:

grub> root (hd0,0)

grub> setup (hd0)

grub> quit

Reboot the computer.